# How to match every page that ends on .php EXEPT OF

Tags: regex, nginx, expression

How can I match every page that ends on .php exept of download.php and upload.php?

This matches every page that ends on .php

```
\.php($|\?)
```

When I use

```
^(^(?!download|upload).*)\.php$
```

download.php is not matched. But however somethingdownload.php is matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you wanted to use what is known as the [tempered greedy token solution](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed).

```
^(?:(?!download|upload).)*\.php$
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fzKtXn/1) -
Your [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is currently triggered just at the [`^` start](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).
To [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the part until `.php` wrap in a *group*: [`^((?:(?!download|upload).)*)\.php$`](https://regex101.com/r/fzKtXn/2)